# NtCurrentTeb() on C++ Rad Studio 10

Tags: c++

I've made this declaration in my include file:

```
 __inline struct _PEB * NtCurrentPeb() { return NtCurrentTeb()->ProcessEnvironmentBlock; }
```

Leading the file also includes these values:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <WinNT.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")
```

But the compiler (Rad Studio XE 10) gives me this error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'NtCurrentTeb'

Where am I wrong? What is missing?

Comment: Where's `NtCurrentTeb()` declared? Did you miss to include another header?

Comment: But the call it is not included in ntdll.lib?

Comment: What do you mean _the call is not included_? You need `NtCurrentTeb()` declared somewhere (probably from an included header), to call it in that inlined function definition.

Comment: It is to understand:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh285210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Then we go I have to build me a call? reading microsoft does not seem.

Comment: I'm not sure if the required `Winnt.h` header is the same as the used `#include <WinNT.h>`. There could be also the possibility you're missing some of the other requirements stated in the docs (e.g. _"Available in Windows 7 and later versions of Windows."_).

Comment: it doesn't appear that you actually `#include`d your custom include file.

Comment: If i compiled the same procedure with VC 2015 the compile fine good. If I do a search on the procedure opens me winnt.h file. Correctly. Instead of XE10 although the call to winnt.h not find the procedure. strange.